# Topological embedding coordinates induced my embedding

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Edited (Thanks to Paul Frost for Clarification)

Suppose we have a topological embedding $H:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

By definitition of topological embeddings, $H$ is a homeomorphism onto its image and that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is manifold. So, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has coordinates, we write as $(x^1,...,x^n)$. If one considers $H(\mathbb{R}^n)$, this set can be purely described topologically by homeomorphism $(x^1,...,x^n)\leftrightarrow H(x^1,...,x^n)$.

So the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the domain give, or as Paul Frost wrote, $H(\mathbb{R}^n)$ *recieves coordinates* from the domain.

These coordinates on $H(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are called $H$-coordinates and are clearly naturally so.

This is compatible with the manifold definition, because since $H$ is homeomorphism onto its image, $H(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a manifold. In more generality,

**Observation:** As Paul Frost wrote, the codomain doesn't have to be $\mathbb{R}^n$. Specifically,

If $H:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow X$ is homeomorphism onto image, then $H(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a a manifold of dimension $n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $H(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has a global chart. Specifically, $(H(\mathbb{R}^n),h(x^1,...,x^n))$, where $(\mathbb{R}^n,(x^1,...,x^n))$ is chart on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: It goes against the intention of this site to rewrite the question after an answer has been posted and accepted. If you want to keep track of details missing in that answer, I suggest you write them up in a separate answer. But leave the question untouched (except for cosmetic clarifications), for otherwise the post and the original answer become incomprehensible to future readers.

Comment: I did not write any of what you reply to. It seems like you are replying to comments by Xander Henderson which in the meanwhile have disappeared. Xander Henderson and I are not the same person. --- That being said, I stand by what I said in my first comment here. Why don't you just write up clarifying ideas in a new answer, and leave the question as it was?

Comment: @Xander Henderson why not re edit this post too? Doesn't it conflict the same guidelines as the other post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have an embedding $H : \mathbb R^n \to X$ into a topological space $X$, the subspace $Y  =H(\mathbb R^n) \subset X$ *receives coordinates via $H$* ("$H$-coordinates"). The $H$-coordinates of points $y \in Y$ are nothing else than the preimages $H^{-1}(y) \in \mathbb R^n$. Thus each $y \in Y$ can be uniquely identfied by the real coordinates of $H^{-1}(y)$ in $\mathbb R^n$.